# Getting error "then is not a function" in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to call get data from file using $http .i make a factory and get result in controller .I want to declare both success and error method .But I am getting this error 
**accountDetailService.callAccountDetailService.then is not a function**
here is my code

http://plnkr.co/edit/eGaPwUdPgknwDnozMJWU?p=preview

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])
  .controller('showhidecntr', function($scope, $window,accountDetailService) {
    $scope.hgt = $window.innerHeight / 3;
    //alert($scope.hgt)
    accountDetailService.callAccountDetailService.then(function(data){
      console.log(data);
    }).error(function(data){
       console.log("error"+data);
    })

  }).factory('accountDetailService',['$http','$q', function($http, $q) {

        return {
            callAccountDetailService: function(callback){
                $http.get('default.json').success(callback).error(callback);
            }
        };

    }])
```

;

Comment: you are missing the return statement in front of $http

Comment: could you please give codepen

Comment: you provide a fidle if you want it to be fixed, or you can just place the return in front of $http and get it working ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The promises only works when you return the callback object. 
there is 2 way to fix this problem.

1- change your factory code to this code:

```
            return $http.get('default.json').success(callback).error(callback);
```

2- you can just use success instead of then and remove the success and error callback from your factory.

if it's up to me , I will always choose option 1, because it's more clear and easy to understand.

good luck and have fun.

Comment: could you please give plunker